# Полином без классов

Tags: c++

захотел написать калькулятор для полиномов и нашел интересный раздел суперпозиции, поэтому написал вот такую ​​функцию но не получилось, в чем ошибка? P.s. код пишу без классов(если нужно то ввод полиномов такой например:1+2х+3х^2 и тд.)
я ввел два полинома 1+2х+3х^2 и вишло не 27x4+36x3+36x2+16x+6

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов проблема в обчислении,вишло не то что ожидал

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов как я понимаю супер позиция ето например 2х+2 и 2х+1 то суперпозиция ето 2(2х+1)+2 ну и у меня не вишло

Comment: Ну так по используемой вами формуле ничего и не выйдет, у вас что-то типа ужасно неэффективного вычисления произведения...

Comment: @Harry а как исправить?

Comment: Стандарт :) Знали бы вы, как бесит, когда "почему у меня не работает" приводит не к "понятно, я пошел думать и работать", а к "а как исправить?" Переписать правильно. Простой формулы нет, берете бином Ньютона и реализуете...

Comment: @Harry проблема в том что в интернете нет даже примерно как это делать, поэтому ничего не получается, только нашел эту формулу и ничего не получается

Comment: @Harry Типа я вас понимаю, потому шо сам порой помогаю людям, которые порой задают на вид глупые вопросы, но для них это трудно, и сейчас вам наверняка тоже так кажется, но на самом деле это зависит как для кого

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов 1)1+4x+10x^2+12x^3+9x^4 2)ну под суперпозицией понимаю вот например беру другие полином 2+2х и например 2+3х  то суперпозиция 2+2(2+3х)

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов не там все получаеться,просто я думаю что одной функцией ето не возможно сделать,может можно как то сделать через умножение и схеми горнера

Comment: Ну вам надо писать отдельно умножение, отдельно - возведение в степень, и потом все это соединять в одно целое. Можно написать умножение полиномов, сложение полиномов и по схеме Горнера реализовывать суперпозицию. Работа никак не на 15 минут...

Comment: @Harry умножение есть,а возведение в степень щас попробую

Comment: @Harry но если по схеме горнера то возведение в степень не нужно

Comment: А я что написал? Можно так - .... Можно эдак - .... И там, где "эдак", т.е. где упомянута схема Горнера, степень не упоминается, правда?

Comment: @Harry ага понял вроде,

Answer (score 5):

Вообще странно, что вы желаете написать полиномы без классов, ведь их нормальная реализация занимает внушительный объем кода, да и нужны эти самописные полиномы разве что для практики в написании классов, но это ваше дело.

Суперпозиция (композиция) многочленов `F(X)` и `G(X)` - это операция, результатом которой является `F(G(X))`. Это может быть как конкретное значение при заранее заданном `X`, так и новый многочлен `H(X)`, который принимает эти значения при любых значениях `X`.

Например, если `F(X)` - квадратичная функция, то есть `F(X) = A*X^2 + B*X + C`. Тогда `H(X) = F(G(X)) = A*G(X)^2 + B*G(X) + C = A*G(X)*G(X) + B*G(X) + C`. Тогда достаточно просто увидеть, как можно получить `H(X)`, когда у вас реализована операция умножения многочленов. Также если вы знаете о схеме Горнера, то вы можете применить ее и тут, благодаря чему эффективность алгоритма намного увеличится.

Приведу свою реализацию композиции многочленов, но буду использовать `std::vector` вместо чистых массивов просто потому, что я уже писал такое именно на них. В моем случае `vector[i]` хранит коэффициент `F(X)` при одночлене степени `i`. То есть `F(X) = 2*X^2 - 5*X + 7` хранится как `vector<int> f = {7, -5, 2}`.

```cpp
//Удаление старших одночленов с нулевыми коэффициентами
void normalize(vector<int>& f) 
{
    while (f.size() > 1 && f.back() == 0)
        f.pop_back();
}

//Умножение многочленов F(X) * G(X)
vector<int> multiple(vector<int>& f, vector<int>& g) 
{
    vector<int> h(f.size() + g.size() - 1, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < f.size(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < g.size(); j++)
            h[i + j] += f[i] * g[j];

    normalize(h);
    return h;
}

//Композиция многочленов F(G(X))
vector<int> composition(vector<int>& f, vector<int>& g)
{
    vector<int> h = { f.back() };
    for (int i = f.size() - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        h = multiple(h, g);
        h[0] += f[i];
    }

    normalize(h);
    return h;
}

//Хоть сколько-то наглядный вывод многочлена
void print(vector<int>& f)
{
    for (int i = f.size() - 1; i > 0; i--)
        cout << f[i] << "*X^" << i << " + ";
    cout << f[0] << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> f = { 7, -5, 2 };
    print(f); //2*X^2 + -5*X^1 + 7
    vector<int> g = { 3, 2, 1 };
    print(g); //1*X^2 + 2*X^1 + 3
    vector<int> h = composition(f, g);
    print(h); //2*X^4 + 8*X^3 + 15*X^2 + 14*X^1 + 10

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: извините а без вектора можно?

Comment: Ну замените все вектора на динамические массивы. Сама логика от этого не изменяется. Просто везде где используется `vector.size()`, замените это на `array_size`, а функцию `normalize` просто не используйте или вместо удаления элементов уменьшайте размер массива, но это ведет к утечкам памяти. Объявление вектора `vector<int> vec(size, 0)` тождественно `int *array = new int[size]()`

Comment: я сверху сделал,но чет мусор какойто,не могли б поправить?